# Configuring a Remote Git Repository On A Networked Server?

Tags: git

I am using Git as my method of managing source control. Currently I am just using Git on my local machine with a local repository. I have a networked server setup which I would like to configure a repository on. Essentially I want to be able to push to the networked server, thus cutting out the need to use GitHub.

Someone has mentioned that the use of a daemon will be needed so that i can essentially tell Git to push to a repository at an arbitrary URL, for example "MyServer:8443/GitRepository/".

Unfortunately, I am completely lost on how exactly I go about doing this and would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 6):

What OS is your server? It's a lot easier with a linux server.

You can do it as follows (presuming you already have [ssh](http://suso.org/docs/shell/ssh.sdf) access). I shall call your server sally, and your desktop dan, for convenience.

Connect to your server from your desktop:

```
ssh sally
```

then on the server, create somewhere to keep your repos:

```
mkdir -p /var/git
cd /var/git
```

Now you have somewhere to keep stuff. Next we will presume you already have a git repo for your project called 'project1.git' on your desktop. You can do the following for each new project:

Still on the server

```
mkdir project1.git
cd project1.git
git --bare init   #use bare as you don't need the files checked out on the server
touch git-daemon-export-ok   #for later if you set up the git daemon (optional)
```

Then back on the desktop, push your changes to the new repo on the server:

```
git remote add origin sally:/var/git/project1.git
git push origin master
```

That's it. You can then clone from another machine with

```
git clone sally:/var/git/project1.git project1.git
```

---

Optional extras:

- Set up the [git daemon][2], to share without needing ssh access.
- Set up [gitweb][3] to get a nice web interface

2 - http: //www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html

3 - http: //git.or.cz/gitwiki/Gitweb

Comment: It's Windows Server 2008....But thanks for the tip! :-D

Answer (score 2):

Just push through SSH; setup your remote as `MyServer:/path/to/gitrepo` and away you go.  If you want to provide read-only access to the Internet at large, you can either use HTTP, or `git-daemon` to support `git://` protocol URLs.

Comment: To avoid having complete shell access, use `git-shell` along with SSH as the user shell.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link to be the most helpful : 
[Intall Git on Windows Server 2008](http://www.shannoncornish.com/blog/2009/04/git-server-windows-2008/)